# Inline Python support for passing filehandle from perl

Tags: python, perl

While Trying Inline python as a interface from perl to python , I am facing below issue.
This is the code where fun is a subroutine inside python and I am trying to call it from perl

test.pl:

```
use Inline Python => <<END;

def fun(fh):
    print(fh)
END

my $FH;
open($FH, ">", '/tmp/x.cth');
print $FH "hello\n";
fun($FH);
```

When I execute test.pl, It prints "None", and its not able to pass FileHandle to python code. Or passing None to python. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot pass a Perl filehandle to Python. But you can try pass a [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor):

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Inline Python => <<END;
import os
def fun(fd):
    with os.fdopen(int(fd), 'a') as file:
        file.write("Hello from Python")
END

my $fn = 't.txt';
open (my $fh, ">", $fn) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
say $fh "hello";
$fh->flush();
fun(fileno($fh));
close $fh
```

The content of `t.txt` after running the script is:

```
$ cat t.txt
hello
Hello from Python
```